# Jackson deserializing Optional throws NoSuchFieldError

Tags: java, spring, jackson, option-type

I developing a Spring Boot application and I tried to include an `Optional<String>` (`java.lang`) field in one of my models, so If the `@RestController` I am using with won't get such a field, it will include it as an `Optional.empty()`. Every time I call the method via POST I get a `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: _valueInstantiator` exception. I started experimenting and made a stripped down version of the deserializer, that still gives me the error:

The model:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;

import java.util.Optional;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Test {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Optional<String> nickname;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Optional<String> getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }

    public void setNickname(Optional<String> nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }
}
```

And the deserialization snippet:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Jdk8Module j = new Jdk8Module();
j.configureAbsentsAsNulls(true);//tried using true and false too
mapper.registerModule(j);
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS);
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);


mapper.readValue("{\"id\":1, \"name\":\"a\", \"nickname\":\"asd\"}", Test.class);
```

If I don't include the `nickname` property at all, it still gives me the same error.
[image]

Jackson versions:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

...

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Tried it with this controller (same exception):

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/test",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Test test(
            @RequestBody Test test
    ) {
        return test;//<-- did not even reach the breakpoint here
    }
```

Comment: show your controller code.

Comment: @pvpkiran I don't think the controller's code matters, because the code I included is separate from the controller, but still gives me the exception.

Comment: I tried ur exact code. I didnt get any error. I am using jackson-datatype-jdk8 verion 2.8.5

Comment: @pvpkiran Which versions did you use? Did you create a spring initializer project?

Comment: I did get the error when I had different versions of `jackson-datatype-jdk8` and `jackson-databind` it works fine when the versions are the same. Make sure you use the same versions.

Comment: This error is typically thrown if you only partially recompile your code. You've got old code that is referencing a field that no longer exists in the recompiled class files.

Comment: @MehrajMalik I did a maven clean and compile, but It still gives me the error.

Comment: @Oleg Thanks, the reason behind the error was the different versions I was using. I think I used a newer versions for the `jackson-datatype-jdk8` than the jackson library included default by the spring boot release.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By initially running your code I found code is working fine with `jackson-datatype-jdk8`'s version 2.8.6 but not working with version you are using (i.e 2.9.2). Use below dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: A bit further digging - Spring Boot 1.5.8 includes jackson-databind 2.8.10 which does not work well together with jackson-databind-jdk8 2.9.x. Downgrading that to the latest 2.8 version (2.8.11 at the time of writing) fixed that issue for me, too.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because from UI you are sending a `String` and in your model it is expecting an `Optional<String>`.

Change your `Test` to :

```
public class Test {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String nickname;
```

---

Update from comment :

It will give exception similar to below :

> nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct
>   instance of java.util.Optional: no String-argument constructor/factory
>   method to deserialize from String value

Comment: The whole purpose of the `Optional` would be to include the nickname if it is present and let it be `Optional.empty()` if the value is missing from the input.

Comment: I agree with you, but here the Jackson uses the getter and setter methods to bind the data from requestBody to model. And then it finds the incompatible setter and getter, which results in exception.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same cause, but we ran into the same error (`java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: _valueInstantiator`) while upgrading the jackson dependency to a newer version (2.9.4).

In our case it helped to completely rebuild the whole project (f.e. `gradle clean build` if you use gradle).