# Jackson cannot deserialize Optional, throws NoSuchFieldError

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, option-type

I want to use the Optional type in my classes but everytime when jackson tries to deserialize an incoming JSON to a java classes i get the error

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: _valueInstantiator
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.OptionalDeserializer.withResolved(OptionalDeserializer.java:38) ~[jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.OptionalDeserializer.withResolved(OptionalDeserializer.java:10) ~[jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ReferenceTypeDeserializer.createContextual(ReferenceTypeDeserializer.java:74) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handlePrimaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:650) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:490) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:293) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
```

I know theres already a thread about this: [Jackson deserializing Optional throws NoSuchFieldError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47132810/jackson-deserializing-optional-throws-nosuchfielderror) and 
I've already tried changing the `jackson-java8` extension to an older type but nothing works. I keep getting the `noSuchFieldError` or just a plain null pointer exception when i'm using a version from 2014. Can anyone tell me if theres something else i could try? Because i really want to use Optionals, thank you. Heres the code of the java class. The first field causes the error:

```
public class SeedRecordQuery {
    private Optional<List<Double>> monthlyTemperatureCurve;
    private Optional<FilterWrapper> filterWrapper;

    public Optional<List<Double>> getMonthlyTemperatureCurve() {
        return monthlyTemperatureCurve;
    }

    public void setMonthlyTemperatureCurve(Optional<List<Double>> monthlyTemperatureCurve) {
        this.monthlyTemperatureCurve = monthlyTemperatureCurve;
    }

    public Optional<FilterWrapper> getFilterWrapper() {
        return filterWrapper;
    }

    public void setFilterWrapper(Optional<FilterWrapper> filterWrapper) {
        this.filterWrapper = filterWrapper;
    }
}
```

I've tried using an untyped `Optional` but the same error occurs so the error is not caused by the generic type `List<Double>`

EDIT: I made a workaround that allows me to get the JSON values as optionals, but its not ideal:

```
private List<Double> monthlyTemperatureCurve;
private FilterWrapper filterWrapper;
@JsonIgnore
private Optional<List<Double>> monthlyTemperatureCurveOptional;
@JsonIgnore
private Optional<FilterWrapper> filterWrapperOptional;

public SeedRecordQuery() {
    monthlyTemperatureCurveOptional = Optional.ofNullable(monthlyTemperatureCurve);
    filterWrapperOptional = Optional.ofNullable(filterWrapper);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `jackson-datatype-jdk8` in your dependencies but you also need to register the `Jdk8Module` in your mapper.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
String json = "{\"monthlyTemperatureCurve\":[2.5,4.3]}";
SeedRecordQuery seedRecordQuery = mapper.readValue(json, SeedRecordQuery.class);
```

**Edit**

If you are using a globally configured `ObjectMapper` in your spring application, you have to configure it to your needs:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am never instantiating an object mapper. Object mapper is used behind the scene by spring to turn a JSON field into an optional. I never use the objectmapper manually anywhere in my code.

Comment: Then you have to configure your `ObjectMapper` globally for your spring application, and add the Jdk8Module. If you are not touching your ObjectMapper in your spring application, it means you are using the default configuration

Comment: ok thank you, i will test this in an hour or so and then i will get back at you and tell whether it worked or not.